# Establecer alto con grid-colum

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid-layout

Con **grid-colum** se puede hacer por ejemplo que un grid se diferente al resto, por ejemplo que ocupe una sola fila:

```
grid-column: 1 / -1
```

Pero mantendrá el mismo alto que el resto de grid's. ¿Como puedo personalizar su altura? si pongo `height = 10%`; o `height = 20px;`, mantiene la misma altura.

Aquí se puede ver como funciona **grid-colum**:
https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid-column

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se puede ver como el grid 1 tiene el mismo height que los grid's del 2 al 7

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un esquema o dibujo de lo que quieres hacer exactamente? ¿A que te refieres cuando dices que todos los grids tienen la misma altura?

Comment: He añadido a la pregunta lo que me pides, espero que con esto se entienda más lo que busco conseguir.

Comment: Ah vale, te refieres a las filas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sí quieres que cada fila tenga una altura diferente puedes usar la propiedad `grid-template-rows` y poner la altura que quieras a cada fila. En mi ejemplo pongo `150px` a la segunda fila:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: auto 150px auto;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, había visto lo del `grid-template-rows`, pero pensaba que se especificaba en el grid concreto, no en el contenedor, pero de esta manera has de saber por adelantado cual es la fila afectada.

Comment: Llamas grid a las filas pero el grid es el contenedor. El número de filas puede cambiar dependiendo del tamaño de cada "celda" así que no hay otra forma de establecer la altura de una fila concreta.

Answer (score 1):

En CSS:

```
display: grid;    
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;    
line-height: 40px;
```

Esto hace una malla de 4 columnas con ancho auto y de alto 40px las filas que sean. No hace falta saber cuantas va a haber, agregas dinamicamente todas las que quieras y son de 40px de alto.

Solo he probrado con chrome y edge, no se el resto.